# Java calling a method from my main class from another class

Tags: java, swing, methods, program-entry-point, invoke

Two classes in the same package,

The main class that has a combo of public static and instance variables.
It creates an instance of the class called `instance`.

Another class `Login`, not a subclass, does it's business but I want to call a method from guiInstance from main.

Problem is that I cant seem to get it to work, I cant get the `Login` class to find any methods of the "gui" instance or class despite them being public.

I just made a new package with the config I want and clearly I have got the wrong idea about how calling methods works.

```
public class GUI {

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI instance = new GUI();
    }

    public void ping(){
        System.out.println("that worked");
    }
}


public class Login extends JPanel {

    /** Creates new form Login */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(112, 112, 112)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(215, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(231, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        instance.ping();
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an instance of `GUI` in your `main()` method, but you don't seem to create an instance of `Login`.  I would suggest you pass the `GUI` instance to your `Login` constructor, so in `Login` add something like -

```
private GUI gui = null;
public Login(GUI gui) {
  this.gui = gui;
  initComponents();
}
```

Then in `main()` you can do something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  GUI instance = new GUI();
  Login login = new Login(instance);
  // next I believe you need to make your Frame and components visible
}
```

Comment: spot on, that is not something I have ever done before and it's impossible to google something you think should happen when you dont know what it's called. it all seems so simple now! Thanks!!!

Comment: Nitpick: while certainly correct, personally, I'd prefer to pass some kind of interface to Login, so as not to expose elements of GUI which Login didn't need to know about or should be able to access

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, have you any code pointers for implementing that please?